# Working with Ribbon controls defined in a VSTO add-in using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto, ribbonx

I'm trying to create a ribbon for Office Word 365 with two editboxes and a checkbox.

I have a macro I would like to use that input afterwards.

So far I have used the Ribbon Designer in Visual Studio to create an Add-in ribbon.
[image]

The Add-in shows in Word and it looks like it's supposed to. I just can't figure out how to get the input from the editboxes and checkbox to vba.

The VBA code I have looks like this:

```
Sub PasteAndSelectPicture()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
Dim shp As Word.Shape
Dim lNrIls As Long
Dim lNrShp As Long
Dim rngDoc As Word.Range
Dim rngSel As Word.Range

Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Content
Set rngSel = Selection.Range
rngDoc.End = rngSel.End + 1

'Get an InlineShape
lNrIls = rngDoc.InlineShapes.Count
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Debug.Print rngDoc.InlineShapes.Count, lNrIls

Set ils = rngDoc.InlineShapes(lNrIls + 1)
ils.Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(VAR1)

Set shp = ils.ConvertToShape
shp.IncrementRotation VAR2

shp.ConvertToInlineShape

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'd like the VAR1 and VAR2 to be inputs from the two editboxes.

Answer (score 2):

By design, it's not possible to access Ribbon controls from a project that does not contain that Ribbon's XML. While the VSTO Ribbon Designer is "nice to have" you cannot use it with VBA code - only with code in the VSTO project that contains the Ribbon.

That means you either need to write VB.NET code in the VSTO project, or you need to create the Ribbon XML differently.

If you want to use VBA then you need the Ribbon XML (there is an "Export" option in VSTO). Using the [Custom UI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2010/08/10/23248.aspx) the Ribbon XML can be incorporated into a Word docm or dotm file.

The information in the series of articles [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)) describes how to write VBA code that uses controls in the Ribbon XML. There are also lots of articles, discussions and examples on the Internet, plus a really good book on the subject (RibbonX Customizing the Office 2007 RIbbon).

Comment: Thanks! So, in short, what I read from your reply is, that what I'm trying to do is going to take quite an effort to actually do?

Comment: @Martin "quite an effort" is undefined - I have no way of knowing what you consider that to be. Nor whether a VSTO add-in (rather than a VBA solution) works for you. Working with edit boxes in a Ribbon isn't "difficult" (for me, anyway), but it's not as simple as working with a VBA UserForm, for example.